# Unset Data from Woocommerce Rest API V3

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to create an app thourgh Woocmmerce REST API V3, When i call the api it gives me everything and few things that i don't want in response, is there any way remove unwanted data from response?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://mywebsite.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/?consumer_key=ck_01010101010101010101010101&consumer_secret=cs_01010101010101010101010101&type=variable&stock_status=instock&category=59

You can filter the data during the call but you will still recover a lot of data.
You will only need to extract what you need.

Comment: these are the url parametes, but is there any way if i can remove the data from response,because i need all products but some data is not useful.  i am doing it for WP rest api.

Comment: here is the example

Comment: function my_rest_prepare_celeb( $data, $post, $request ) {
 $_data = $data->data;

 $params = $request->get_params();
 if ( ! isset( $params['id'] ) ) {
  unset( $_data['content'] );
        unset( $_data['template'] );
 

 }

 $data->data = $_data;

 return $data;
}
add_filter( 'rest_prepare_celebrities', 'my_rest_prepare_celeb', 10, 3 );

Comment: this is the hook for WP REST API

Comment: add_filter( 'rest_prepare_celebrities', 'my_rest_prepare_celeb', 10, 3 );

Comment: No I don't think you can do that.
You take everything and then you filter according to your need

http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#list-all-products

Comment: so we need to take all data then filter out at app end

Comment: Yes with a loop